# Excel - sorting and selecting in protected sheet

Tags: excel, sorting, protected

I want to let user sort data on the sheet + let user select cells (to copy them to clipboard) +  keep them uneditable.

The issue here is that sorting requires adding a range with locked cells  (Allow Users to Edit Ranges) and then u just Protect sheet with AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True.

Now sorting works, cells un-editable but you can't select them to copy.
If I make cells selectable than user is able to change values...  that I dont want.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!!

Comment: You can make macro to unprotect sheet, sort and then protect sheet after finish the task.

Answer (score 0):

looks like that only wait is to write a macro. excel build-in functionality doesn't allow both sorting ,selecting and protecting